# Maven: how to assemble a bundle with multiple environments

Tags: maven, deployment, maven-release-plugin

I'd like to assemble a big bundle, which contains some common binaries and confuguration settings along with environment specific things.

E.g.:

```
* lib
* bin
* conf
* env -> uat1 -> conf
* env -> uat2 -> conf
* env -> uat3 -> conf
* env -> uat4 -> conf
```

It could be done easily using Maven Components, if only filesets included in specific environments don't overlap.

For example if  I have:

```
uat1: file_alpha, file_beta, file_uat1
uat2: file_alpha, file_beta, file_uat2
uat3: file_delta, file_gamma, file_uat3
uat4: file_delta, file_gamma, file_uat4
```

I would like to configure common filesets in a single file. E.g. (as for filesets):

```
uat1uat2: file_alpha, file_beta
uat1: [uat1uat2], file_uat1
uat2: [uat1uat2], file_uat2
uat3uat4: file_delta, file_gamma
uat3: [uat3uat4], file_uat3
uat4: [uat3uat4], file_uat4
```

Unfortunatelly I found, that Maven doesn't support sub-components or parametrized components (for uat1 I put file to /env/uat1/conf, for uat2 I put file to /env/uat2/conf).

What would be solution to address my deployment needs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understood your question, so here's half an answer.

I use this iterator plugin to bundle my env. Perhaps it can help you?

http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/